# Multivalued Primary Key?

Tags: mysql

I am attempting a database question however I got stuck at this point, Lets say I had two entities RP and FP. The attributes for RP are A,B and C with A being the primary key. For FP the the attributes are X,Y,Z primary key X.

FP is weak entity which is dependent on RP so after creating my relational schema the primary key for FP is (A,X) with A being a foreign key which references the primary key of RP, my problem is that an example of FP has multiple values of A that make up one FP.

Example, FP 'FP01' is made from RP 'RP01' and RP 'RP02'.....Y and Z are just descriptions for FP.

My tuples look like this...which is duplicate data, as both rows will need to carry the same descriptions for the same FP

|....X....|....A....|........Y........|.........Z........|

|.FP01.|.RP01.|descrition1|description2|

|.FP01.|.RP02.|descrition1|description2|

I was thinking of making A a multivalued attribute but A is part of the primary key and I am unsure if that is possible to do or correct for that matter. How do I handle this?

Comment: the primary key for FP is X or (A,X) ?

Comment: If this is a homework question can you please tag it as such?

Comment: In one point you say that `FP`'s Primary Key is `X`. In another you say it's the `(A,X)`. Which statement is correct?

Comment: I love the use of periods to space variable-width text. Y'know, rather than reading the formatting FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between `RP` and `FP` is one-to-many, then this is OK.

`FP.A` is not unique and is a `FOREIGN KEY` to `RP(A)`

`FP(A,X)` is unique (it's the `PRIMARY KEY`) so there is no problem.

---

The tables are not normalized though if the attributes `Y` and `Z` depend on the `X` only and not on the whole Primary Key `(A,X)`. You need to split the `FP` table into two tables in that case.

Comment: So if I were to split FP into FP & FP_Descrition and use and attribute FD_ID in FP_Desription as a foreign key to reference X in FP I should have everything covered?

Comment: Then (if I understand correctly), tables `RP(A,B,C)` and `FP(X,Y,Z)` with a joining table `JOIN_RP_FP(A,X)` would be ok.